# Timeout Error: JSON Requests in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, python-requests

I have pandas dataframe of 25000 entries and in one column I have all the URLs.
What I am trying to do is retrieve JSON for all those URLS.
What is an efficient way to achieve this since simple loop results in a Timeout error?
Moreover, I have also tried using time.sleep() but to no avail. What happens then is that some rows are read and some are not.

```
import time
def get_reviews(review):
    reviews = []
    try:
        response = requests.get(review)
        json_data = response.json()
        for j in json_data:
            if j['language'] == 'en':
                reviews.append(j['text'])
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
    return reviews

batch_size = 20
start = 0
end = 10
for epoch in range(int(data.shape[0]/batch_size)):
    data['reviews'][start:end] = data['reviews'][start:end].apply(get_reviews)
    start += batch_size
    end += batch_size
print(data.head(30))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a retry decorator on the function. I had a similar problem i solved by just looping till i got the webpage.

http://winstonlarson.com/scraping-timeouts